# Improve accuracy on convolutional neural network

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I'm trying to train a convolutional neural network to classify sentences. I take the code from [here](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/)

The code works fine in one of my datasets. However, on another dataset, its performance is very poor. Two datasets are comparable in terms of volumes and sentence length. For the dataset with the poor performance, I notice the loss function decreases after steps. Here the blue is for training set and the read is for test set.
[image]

And here is the accuracy:
[image]
As you can see, the loss values on the test set decrease, but the accuracy values are almost the same.
Can you suggest me how to fix it?
Thank you very much.

Comment: How many category labels do you have in each data set and what are the differences in the nature of the text between each?

Comment: @jmp For the both datasets, number of classes is 4. In fact, both datasets are tweets collected from twitter. The dataset with good performance is created by myself via twitter stream API while the other is from a website. The difference is that I don't use any filter to eliminate tweets from automatic bots, like weather or recruitment. For the dataset from the website, they only keep tweets from normal people. Two datasets have almost the same number of examples and I apply the same pre-processing technique.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with a smaller learning rate?

Comment: Current learning rate I'm using is 1e-4 with Adam optimizer. I've tried with 1e-5, and now it shows a very slow convergence.

Comment: That sounds good. You can make it a bit bigger to make it fast. Please let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an exponential decaying learning rate--starts big at first (say 0.1) and then slows down over iterations.